# how to add an average rating of topic as picture star

Tags: php, rating, phpbb

how to add an average rating of topic as picture star ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what your code does - but you could do something like

```
<img id="image" src="#">
```

and then in a java script file put

```
var x =  value;
document.getElementById("image").src = 'url/default/starts-'x'.gif";
```

Comment: Damn, I was wondering how I was not understanding your code - Now it just hit me ;)  I'm afraid I don't know PHP.

Comment: may otherwise ... how to make different image for different values​​?

Comment: Creating images is quite hard to do automatically - I would suggest creating all of the images and naming them in a logical format, such as 1.gif 2.gif 3.gif.